# how to select row names and row for any mismatch found in a row data frame

Tags: r, split, subset

I have a data frame like this in `R`

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("L", "L", "P", "P"), V2=c("M", "M", "M" , "M"), V3=c("X", "X", "X", "X" ), V4=c( "V","V","V","V"))
```

I would like to subset this data frame based on the mismatches found by row and create two different tables like this

```
df1 
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  L  M  X  V
2  L  M  X  V

df2
V1 V2 V3 V4
1 P  M  X  V
2 P  M  X  V
```

I know that can be done by `split(df, df$V1)` but I would like to know if there is a more "automatic" way in which **I do not have to specify the col with mismatches**
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` option -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(across()) %>% group_split()

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  V1    V2    V3    V4   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 L     M     X     V    
#2 L     M     X     V    

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  V1    V2    V3    V4   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 P     M     X     V    
#2 P     M     X     V
```

Answer (score 7):

In base R, you could use:

```
split(df, do.call(paste, df))

$`L M X V`
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  L  M  X  V
2  L  M  X  V

$`P M X V`
  V1 V2 V3 V4
3  P  M  X  V
4  P  M  X  V
```

Comment: thank you, but again, how can I keep the rownames? thaks!

Comment: @lana Which rownames? There default rownames have been kept. ie 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 7):

You can use `df` directly in `split` (Thanks to @27-ϕ-9 for the comment!)

```
split(df, df)
#$L.M.X.V
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  L  M  X  V
#2  L  M  X  V
#
#$P.M.X.V
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#3  P  M  X  V
#4  P  M  X  V
```

Or use it with `interaction` in `split`:

```
split(df, interaction(df))
#$L.M.X.V
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  L  M  X  V
#2  L  M  X  V
#
#$P.M.X.V
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#3  P  M  X  V
#4  P  M  X  V
```

Comment: but how can I preserve rownames in both data frames?

Comment: The rownames are preserved.

Answer (score 3):

a `data.table` option is

```
library(data.table)
split(setDT(df), by = names(df))

# $L.M.X.V
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1:  L  M  X  V
# 2:  L  M  X  V
# 
# $P.M.X.V
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1:  P  M  X  V
# 2:  P  M  X  V
```

Comment: yes it works perfect, any idea about how to `keep rownames` in both df? Thanks!